# Where to store the refresh token safely

Tags: reactjs, jwt

Where should i save refresh token,
I save it in my DB but when I send expired JWT so when i try to valid I cant get the payload I save there.
Is this safe to decode  with atob the JWT so I get the payload and get the username and find in the db the save refresh token.
Because if i save in local storage this is unsafe cause us save there a long live token instead only the JWT(the short live one)

I try to save it cookies but CSRF attack also a problem even if i add the httponly and the secure one
Please correct me if i wrong

**EDIT:**
I also wanted to ask how i do silent log in,
Is this like i do setInterval for 14m so i get the new token even if the user don't do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose between memory or cookie. If you can use cookies, then best choice is cookie! CSRF attack dont be success, if you store it in cookies, another site don't have access to another site cookies. And you have access from XSRF attacks too, becose you neve send refrash token to resource server, it's only for auth server.

Comment: well ya but why should I  save the refresh token in cookies or local storage and try to decode it

Comment: Local storage is not good choice. Memory or cookies. You have token for renew access token. And hacker will not be in time for decode your messages for getting access token. Access token live is about 5 minutes.

Comment: I found link for explain you: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/token-storage

Comment: thanks you for help me,
i read it already but if the refresh token sit in the client side the time for decoded increase because you have 1d or 2d to refresh token, plus cookies open to CSRF token,
which LocalStorage open to XSS but react sanitize so basically most of the XSS part of  XXS attack is not possible
like my thinking is  put interval for 1 min before the token is expired send to db to get a new token

Comment: Did you get JWT-hadbook? https://auth0.com/resources/ebooks/jwt-handbook

Comment: and how i save in memory